# Query including sum from two tables and join them

Tags: php, sql, join

I have two tables:

Invoice

```
id | name | invoice_number | invoice_total
```

Balancesheet

```
id | name | invoice_number | amount_received | discount
```

I want an SQL query to join them grouped by name, and want to sum of invoice_total from the invoice table, and sum of amount_received and sum of discount for individual name from balancesheet table.

Result should be:

```
    name | sum(invoice_total) | sum(amount_received) | sum(discount)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: don't use capitalized  text  ... in web this is like SCREAM

Comment: Here at Stackoferlow, you should at least provide users with what have you tried, not just ask for something to be done for you ^^

Comment: this is my first post, I will keep in mind next time. Thanks 
@Haitam
scaisEdge

Comment: then  you should update your question and use lowercase  ..

Comment: could not get the results, Thanks for help to improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need  only exact match for both the tales between tha names You can use inner join  and group by

```
 select table_1.name, sum(a.invoce_total), sum(AMOUNT_RECEIVED), sum(DISCOUNT)
 from invoice table_1
 inner join BALANCESHEET table_2 on table_1.name = table_2.name
 group by table_1.name
```

if you need  also partial match you can use left join

```
 select table_1.name, sum(a.invoce_total), sum(AMOUNT_RECEIVED), sum(DISCOUNT)
 from invoice table_1
 left join BALANCESHEET table_2 on table_1.name = table_2.name
 group by table_1.name
```

Answer (score 0):

It might need tweaking slightly to take into account your database structure, but try this:

```
select 
    sum(invoice.invoice_total) - sum(balancesheet.amount_received) - sum(balancesheet.discount) as total
from
    invoice
left join
    balancesheet
on
    invoice.name = balancesheet.name
group by
    invoice.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT 
    `NAME`, 
    SUM(`INVOICE_TOTAL`) AS invTotal, 
    SUM(`AMOUNT_RECEIVED`) AS amtRxd, 
    SUM(`DISCOUNT`) AS totalDiscount 
    FROM `TABLE-1` T1 
        LEFT JOIN `TABLE-2` T2 
            ON T1.NAME=T2.NAME 
    GROUP BY T1.NAME
```